# Calling ggplot from function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=2:11)
ggplot(df,aes(x=a,y=b)) + geom_point()+geom_text(aes(label=a,x=a+0.1))
```

This works.

However for some reason the following doesn't work:

```
plotGG <- function(data,shift) {
  ggplot(data,aes(x=a,y=b)) + geom_point()+geom_text(aes(label=a,x=a+shift))
}
plotGG(df,.1)
```

Any clues??